# Dado Shelf Stopper

Tags: design, storage

I want to build some shelves to store trays of dice. The trays are 13.7" x 8.6" x 1.37" and are ~4.5 lbs when completely filled with dice. I want to pull the shelves out far enough to open the tray, but not come all of the way out of the storage box.

I put some dowels on my design as that is what I would try first, but I have no idea if this will work in practice or how long they will last. What's the best (inexpensive) option to stop the shelves from coming out completely?

Here's my design as I would try to build it today: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jsiPei6bP1y-dice-tray-storage[image]

Comment: The usual places sell nylon stops that you can install so you have the usual "lift up a little and slide in" drawer styles., Or you can make your own. These are pretty simple to install., I think we might be missing some detail here that would explain the reason behind your question. What about these drawers makes using off-the-shelf stops difficult?

Comment: One note is that you'll need a little extra length in the tray, so that it can allow the container to open completely while still on the tray. I'd guess 3 inches or so.

Comment: @jdv This may be what I am seeking. 1) I wasn't aware of them. 2) I don't see how I can incorporate them into my design.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I figured allowing the tray to open vertically and giving an extra 1/4" would be enough. I'm always trying to minimize wasted material. I've never done this before. 3" seems excessive to me, but I'm willing to learn from the experience of others. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I can't quite tell from the drawing. Is this a case where the drawer itself holds a closed case. So you need to allow for the drawer to pull out enough to raise the lid on the case? If so, all you need is some mechanism that "catches" the drawer to allow the case lid to open freely, with some lean so it stays open. You might want to share the contruction details you have in mind (or the problem you are trying to solve) otherwise the question won't get much traction.

Comment: I pulled the 3" number from my nether regions as a safe guess. I can assure you that your tray isn't going to hang successfully on 1/4" of wood in a dado. Experiments will tell you where in the middle you might land.

Comment: @jdv It sounds to me like you understand what I'm trying to accomplish. I have trays containing dice. I want to store each tray on it's own shelf. I want the shelf to pull out and allow me to open the tray without removing the tray from the shelf.

I was under the impression that the TinkerCAD link would allow you to view / edit my 3D design; am I mistaken?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I can definitely build and test multiple designs until I get to something that works. I was just hoping to leverage other people's experience.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Apologies. When I was talking about the 3", I thought you were saying that 3" was needed for clearance to just open the container all of the way. I was looking over my project today and just realized you meant that 3" would be needed to remain in the dado to keep the whole thing from falling on my foot! Thanks for the recommendation.